# Report progress using BackgroundWorker report only for the first time

Tags: c#, winforms

I want my application will show on my form my class properties so I started my class with `BackgroundWorker` and create `ProgressChanged`.

my class:

```
public class DumpFile
{
    PacketDevice _device;
    public int _packetsCount;
    public double _bitsPerSecond;
    public double _packetsPerSecond;
    public DateTime _lastTimestamp;
    public delegate void dlgPackProgress(int progress);
    public event dlgPackProgress evePacketProgress;

    public DumpFile(PacketDevice device, string pcapPath)
    {
        _device = device;
        _pcapPath = pcapPath;
        _packetsCount = 1;
    }

    public void startCapturing()
    {
OnPacketProgress(_packetsCount++);

        using (PacketCommunicator communicator = _device.Open(65536, PacketDeviceOpenAttributes.Promiscuous, 1000)) //open the device
        {
            ThreadStart starter = delegate { openAdapterForStatistics(_device); };
            new Thread(starter).Start();

            using (PacketDumpFile dumpFile = communicator.OpenDump(_pcapPath)) //open the dump file
            {
                communicator.ReceivePackets(0, dumpFile.Dump); //start the capture                    
            }
        }
    }
private void OnPacketProgress(int packet)
{
    var handler = evePacketProgress;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(packet);
    }
}

    public void openAdapterForStatistics(PacketDevice selectedOutputDevice)
    {
        using (PacketCommunicator statCommunicator = selectedOutputDevice.Open(100, PacketDeviceOpenAttributes.Promiscuous, 1000)) //open the output adapter
        {
            ThreadStart start = delegate { test(selectedOutputDevice); };
            new Thread(start).Start();

            statCommunicator.SetFilter("tcp"); //compile and set the filter
            statCommunicator.Mode = PacketCommunicatorMode.Statistics; //put the interface in statstics mode                
            statCommunicator.ReceiveStatistics(0, StatisticsHandler);

        }
    }

    public void test(PacketDevice selectedOutputDevice)
    {
        using (PacketCommunicator communicator = selectedOutputDevice.Open(65536, PacketDeviceOpenAttributes.Promiscuous, 1000))
        {
            communicator.ReceivePackets(0, PacketHandler);
        }
    }

    private void PacketHandler(Packet packet)
    {
        string result = _packetsCount.ToString() + ". " + packet.Timestamp.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff") + " length:" + packet.Length;
        _packetsCount++;
    }

    private void StatisticsHandler(PacketSampleStatistics statistics)
    {
        DateTime currentTimestamp = statistics.Timestamp; //current sample time
        DateTime previousTimestamp = _lastTimestamp; //previous sample time
        _lastTimestamp = currentTimestamp; //set _lastTimestamp for the next iteration

        if (previousTimestamp == DateTime.MinValue) //if there wasn't a previous sample than skip this iteration (it's the first iteration)
        {
            return;
        }

        double delayInSeconds = (currentTimestamp - previousTimestamp).TotalSeconds; //calculate the delay from the last sample
        _bitsPerSecond = statistics.AcceptedBytes * 8 / delayInSeconds; //calculate bits per second
        _packetsPerSecond = statistics.AcceptedPackets / delayInSeconds; //calculate packets per second
    }
}
```

start button who start capturing:

```
private void btnStartCapture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timerSniffer.Start();
    btnStartTabSniffer.Enabled = false;
    btnStopTabSniffer.Enabled = true;
    groupBoxSelectTabSniffer.Enabled = false;

    bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    bgWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    bgWorker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bgWSniffer_ProgressChanged);
    bgWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(
        (s3, e3) =>
        {
            DumpFile dumpFile = new DumpFile(deviceForCapturing, pcapFilePathSniffer);

            tshark.evePacketProgress += new DumpFile.dlgPackProgress(
                (packet) =>
                {
                    bgWorker.ReportProgress(packet, dumpFile);
                });

            dumpFile.startCapturing();
        });

    bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
        (s3, e3) =>
        {
            groupBoxSelectTabSniffer.Enabled = true;
        });

    bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

ProgressChanged:

```
private void bgWSniffer_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var dumpFile = (DumpFile)e.UserState;
    lblNumberOfPacketsTabSniffer2.Text = dumpFile._packetsCount.ToString("#,##0");
    lblTrafficRateTabSniffer2.Text = (dumpFile._bitsPerSecond * 0.000001).ToString("0.##") + " Mbit/sec" + " (" + dumpFile._bitsPerSecond.ToString("#,##0") + " Bits/sec" + ")";
    lblPacketsRateTabSniffer2.Text = dumpFile._packetsPerSecond.ToString("#,##0") + " Packets/sec";
}
```

the problem is that my application "get into" ProgressChanged functions but only in one time.

I think I missed something in my class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only find one call to `OnPacketProgress()`, and it's outside of any loop.

```
public void startCapturing()
{
   OnPacketProgress(_packetsCount++);
   ....
}
```

So Yes, that will only be called once.
You need something inside `ReceivePackets()`